# Validation via @Pattern annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I want to validate input form Spring Boot application, and put message to the @Pattern annotation.

But when I run the application and try an invalid input I got only Bad request.

How can I show a meaningful message

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-08-14T20:27:07.901+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "path": "/v1/list"
}
```

SearchCriteria.java

```
package com.event.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchCriteria {


    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", message = "Invalid date format")
    private String from;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", message = "Invalid date format")
    private String to;

}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663801/how-do-i-customize-default-error-message-from-spring-valid-validation

Answer (score 1):

To display a custom message you have to define a `RestControllerAdvice` that will intercept all your exeptions and return a custom message with `ResponseEntity`.

Map your validation exception in your `service` class with a controller custom exception:

```
try {
    // Your custom validation
} catch(ValidationException exception) {
    throw new BadRequest("Message", exception);
}
```

Define a [RestControllerAdvice](https://codedelay.com/exceptionhandler-spring-boot-rest-exception-handling-example/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20for%20Spring%20Boot%20REST%20exception%20handling%2C%20we,in%20the%20entire%20application%20will%20come%20over%20here.) that will return a custom message type:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Message> handleBadRequestException(BadRequestException exception) {
    var error = new Message(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME),
            exception.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(error);
}
```

When an exception is thrown the message 'Message' will be displayed.

[How to set statuscode on postman throw exeption java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031975/how-to-set-statuscode-on-postman-throw-exeption-java/71032319#71032319)

[HTTP status code in case of failure scenario for a REST API which does SMTP connection test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141311/http-status-code-in-case-of-failure-scenario-for-a-rest-api-which-does-smtp-conn/55145923#55145923)

Comment: because it is work on Criteria builder, even though I have added the exception handling, it does not map to the adhoc Exception structure.

Comment: public ResponseEntity<Page<Event>> getEventList(EventPage eventPage,
                                                     @Valid EventSearchCriteria eventSearchCriteria) throws InvalidFieldException{  This is the controller part and this approach does not work